# using proper /tmp on systemd service

Tags: systemd

Let's say i want to create a systemd service and I do want to use regular `/tmp` with no nonsense on top. I know, shocking, right?

I tried to read the manpage for tmpfile.d and there's nothing that looks like this basic use-case, nor how to disable that 'feature' for a single service.

Here's the `.service` in question. As you can see, I couldn't care less for the output other than it being there after it runs so i can inspect in the unlikely case there's a problem. Also by its nature, i do not care for history, as it is stateless, i only would ever want to debug the most recent entries.

```
[Unit]
Description=update dns on boot. also triggered by a timer, i hope.
# mostly from https://mjanja.ch/2015/06/replacing-cron-jobs-with-systemd-timers/

[Service]
Type=simple
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=7
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl -q https://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?asd123= >> /tmp/freedns.log 2>&1
User=nobody
Group=systemd-journal
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "not regular" /tmp? The tmpfiles.d tool has nothing to do with /tmp itself.

Comment: every systemd service sees a different fs location overriding /tmp

Comment: First time I've heard of that feature being enabled for all services by default. (And it _really_ is unrelated to tmpfiles.d.) Which distro is that, and which other services (for example) are affected? Does every single one of them show "PrivateTmp" enabled in `systemctl show foo.service`? And could you grep /etc/pam.d for "pam_namespace"?

Comment: debian9, 10, ubuntu18: mostly following this for the simplest service unit https://mjanja.ch/2015/06/replacing-cron-jobs-with-systemd-timers/